# How to find the direction of current of the circuit?

Tags: current

Okay this is the circuit

[image]

The magnet given is moved up and down continuously at a high rate through the coil and generates a peak voltage of 4V.

I eagerly use the right hand rule in order to find the direction of the current . But what I have found is very-much  confusing.

To use the right hand rule the I assume that the magnetic field is pointing downwards, so without any doubt I point my  fingers towards that direction, I.E I got the dorection of current as rightward. But I am confused with it.

Yes of course I got the direction of current point toward right side, but I am muddled due to this spiral thing in the coil,because in the coil we have springs which are usually take a shape of a circle place in a 3-D space , So I couldn't get a clear idea about where does the current coming out whether it is from the upper end or the lower end of the coil.

So how can I make this puzzle clear?

Comment: You're overthinking it. Look at the rest of the circuit and determine which way the current will flow from those.

Comment: But how could I do that?

Comment: Look at it. Think about it. Technology is harder when you don't apply logic.

Comment: Okay, I did figure out the direction as right side, but where  does it come from, either it is form upper or lower side.

Comment: Is this a trick question or one of those "find 10 reasons this circuit won't work?" type of questions? Because there's so much wrong with the circuit it's hard to decide where to start explaining it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The diagram you posted is a schematic diagram. It is not meant to represent the physical arrangement of the parts, or the direction that the coils turn.
2. Since the magnet is oscillating in and out of the coil, sometimes the current will flow one way and sometimes it will flow the other way. It doesn't really matter which current direction is associated with which direction of movement of the magnet.
3. The connection of LED B is problematic. Your statement that the magnet moving through the coil "generates a peak voltage of 4V" is nonsense given the placement of LED B. I'll leave it as an excercise to understand why.
4. The connection of the resistor is problematic. One end seems to be only connected to itself. This means the resistor has no effect on the operation of the circuit and only makes the drawing more confusing.
5. The connection of LED C is problematic (or maybe part of what you're being asked about). Do you see why LED C will never be forward biased?
6. The schematic drawing conventions are inconsistent. At one place, a connection between two wires is shown with a blob connection. At another, a crossing without a connection is shown with a "jump" to emphasize the lack of connection. At other places, wires cross without either a blob or a jump, so it's not clear whether a connection is intended or not.

Comment: Then the current would be come out from lower end.Am I correct?